# Navigate to another window from a popup in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uipopovercontroller

I used this [SampleCode](https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController) and created two pop-ups, say pop-up1 and pop-up2. From Pop-up1 if a button is pressed another pop-up2 will be displayed. From po-pup2 I need to go for another view. Till pop-up2 its fine, from pop-up2 I couldn't go for a separate view?

I used the below code to remove the popupview.

```
[self dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimationType:MJPopupViewAnimationFade];
    imageShareSubViewController = nil;
```

I used used the below code to navigate to another view.

```
@autoreleasepool {
        ViewController *obj = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:TRUE];
        obj = nil;
    }
```

But the above is not working fine ( i.e., i could navigate to another view ). How to solve this? Am I wrong anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create your navigationController, setRootViewController just like this:

```
//A view controller:
HomeScreen * homeScreen = [[HomeScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeScreen" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homeScreen];

AppDelegate * delegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedAplication]delegate];
delegate.window.rootviewcontroller = navigation;
[homeScreen release];

//add other views

HomeScreen * homeScreen2 = [[HomeScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeScreen" bundle:nil];

[navigation pushViewController: homeScreen2];
[homeScreen2 release];
```